# Using Lobster font

Tags: fonts

I really like `Lobster` font in Instagram logo. I used it in one of the apps and now I think that this font is hard-to-read.

Maybe that is why Instagram uses it only at logo?
Is this logo readable if write many words?

[image]

Comment: It's a display face that is really best used for short bit of text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet will be to stick to using that font for titles, logos and headlines and finding an easier to read font for the main copy. Script fonts are best when used minimally.